# Stratagy to set repeat days alarm in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm really confused about which technique I should use to set and cancel the repeat days alarm.
I have two conditions in my mind.

1. First is that I set all the repeating days alarm at once when alarm is added.
2. Second is that I should check at the time when alarm is triggered that is there any alarm for next day or not.

Problems with my conditions.

1. If i set the repeating days at once and if the user changed the repeating days like user added alarm at 8:30 AM for Monday , Wednesday and Friday and then the user changed the days to Monday and Friday only then how can i keep check on it and cancel it  for Wednesday.
2. In second condition if I check at the time when alarm goes-off for the next day and what if user did not set that alarm for next day and set that same alarm for day after tomorrow? Like user set alarm at Monday 8:30 AM and the same alarm is also set for Wednesday not Tuesday then how can i check this ?

It would be great pleasure if anybody can give me some kind of solution to keep check on it.

Comment: You could use a database to store the date/times for the future alarms. And delete the past ones.

Comment: Bro, then how am i going to set alarm for past days(that are deleted) in the upcoming week.?

Comment: Simply update them to the new month day (today + 7).

Comment: how can i add multiple days against one request code?

Mean my alarmId is 1 and i want add multiple days against this id.?

Comment: Execute multiple inserts or updates.

Comment: if i execute multiple inserts with the same request code it will overwrite the previous executed alarms.

Comment: Only one insert in db for alarm, when the alarm is fired the first time, schedule the next alarm and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can start from Clock app of AOSP https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master

In the specific check how the alarms are implemented in the Alarm class.

In any case you have to schedule the alarm for the "first next day" that is setted, then when the alarm is fired, you need a method that tell you when is the next occurrence.

If an user need to modify the alarm you have to unschedule the existing alarm and reschedule it.

You should also save your alarm to a database because if the device is rebooted all scheduled alarms are lost. So you have to register a boot receiver and re-schedule all the alarms

Comment: Thanks I am studying your code . if i got some problem i will ask u . :)

Comment: As you can see in the provided example, they are using a database, as I suggested: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/provider/ClockDatabaseHelper.java